# gst effectv and noise reduction

Tags: video, gstreamer

I have a somewhat noisy usb camera and I'm using v4l2loopback and ffmpeg to duplicate /dev/video0

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video3  -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video4

So now my dup video0 is on video3 and with video4 I try this

gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video4 !  autovideoconvert ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640,  height=480, framerate=30/1 ! vertigotv ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video5

When I compare "ffplay -i /dev/video3" and "ffplay -i /dev/video5" side-by-side, there is a perfect noise reduction which occurs in /dev/video5, although the vertigotv plugin does warp the output.

I was wondering if there another plugin which will give me the same noise reduction without the vertigotv effect? I'm just trying to eliminate the white speckle noise from my usb camera.